# rake db:migrate and rake db:create both work on test database, not development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Stack Overflow and Ruby on Rails.  My problem is, when I run the command rake db:create or rake db:migrate, the test database is affected, but the development database is not.

rails (3.2.2)

my database.yml:

```
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ticketee_test
  pool: 5
  username: ticketee
  password: my_password_here

development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ticketee_development
  pool: 5
  username: ticketee
  password: my_password_here

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ticketee_production
  pool: 5
  username: ticketee
  password: my_password_here

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Thanks for the suggestion, but I am afraid that isn't the reason.  My RAILS_ENV=development.  When I start the rails server, the server runs the development database. if I run "rails server -e test" then the server uses the test database.  I am still not sure why migrations are running on my test database...

UPDATE:
Based on a suggestion, I commented out all of the database configurations except development, and now I get an error.  I am running postgresql, I have the gem 'pg' installed. First, my new database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ticketee_development
  pool: 5
  username: ticketee
  password: my_password_here

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
#test: &test
#  adapter: postgresql
#  encoding: unicode
#  database: ticketee_test
#  pool: 5
#  username: ticketee
#  password: my_password_here

#production:
#  adapter: postgresql
#  encoding: unicode
#  database: ticketee_production
#  pool: 5
#  username: ticketee
#  password: my_password_here

#cucumber:
#  <<: *test
```

My error message!

```
Someguys-MacBook-Air:ticketee someguy$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Someguys-MacBook-Air:ticketee someguy$ rake db:migrate -t
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:45:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:718:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/someguy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@defaultGems/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Using the database.yml above, rake db:create:all RAN CORRECTLY and created my table.  However, my migration still fails with the same stack trace as the one above.

I changed my database.yml to this:
    development:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/development.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

UPDATE: I completely changed my database.yml to this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Now, this is what happens when I run rake db:drop:all, followed by rake db:migrate.  The rake db:migrate command runs a migration, creating a db/test.sqlite3 AND adding a table to it.  So, my migration is still running on the test environment.  When I run rake environment RAILS_ENV=development db:migrate, the same thing happens and I get a test.sqlite3 file...

Comment: my only suggestion is somehow you've set RAILS_ENV=test in your env?

Comment: Good suggestion, I am afraid that isn't it though.

Comment: Have you try commenting out everything but development and seeing what happens?  May not work but may give you an error leading to the solution.

Comment: Good idea hutsfromshadow, now I am getting an error message in my console! I left more details in my post...

Comment: I had issues with the pg gem so I have used `gem install ruby-pg` instead with no issues.

Comment: Can you put the code for this application on GitHub so we can clone it and poke around in it?

Comment: What is the output of: "echo $RAILS_ENV" on your command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem starting last night. No idea what might have caused this, but finally found a solution that worked. Inside the configure block in config/environments/develop.rb, I added:

```
Rails.env = 'development'
```

I hope that works for you too

Comment: config/environments/name.rb should match the name in database.yml . Rails is more of convention than configuration .

Answer (score 5):

There is a 'brilliant' line in 
activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:

```
environments << 'test' if environment == 'development' && ENV['RAILS_ENV'].nil?
```

which, until jan 8, 2014 looked like:

```
environments << 'test' if environment == 'development'
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your solution could be involving a couple of things. It's possible your your environment is confusing the migration because of existing elements. Reset your database using:

```
rake db:reset
```

or

```
rake db:drop db:create
```

depending on your environment, you should be able to do the migration.

```
rake db:migrate
```

PS - You may have to add `bundle exec` in the beginning of each command.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `host: localhost` in your yml file.

Change your configuration to this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: ticketee_development
  pool: 5
  username: ticketee
  password: my_password_here
```

Comment: I specified the host, same problem.  Remember, I can write migrations to the test database above but I can't write to development under any circumstances.

Comment: I am suspecting a white space issue then.  Open the file in vim with `vi /path/to/database.yml` type `:set list` to see all the invisible characters.

Comment: I just tried that, I see the $ symbols right where I expect to see them thanks for the vi tip though, that will come in handy.

Comment: Dang, I thought for sure that was the issue.

Comment: Issue is that it claims adapter isn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

Forking error! 
Maybe some caching or log problems It shows that nothing of the errors in our code.

My team resolve it.

- delete the project
- git clone the project
- config the database.yml
- start server

Everything is okay!

The same project the errors gone! 
So we think it is env problems or cach or log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="development"

or you can use like

set RAILS_ENV=development

rake db:migrate