# rake db:dump fails when specifying an environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, yaml

I am using the gem yaml_db to generate a db dump.

The regular invocation with

```
rake db:dump
```

works as intended. However when I specify another environment like

```
RAILS_ENV=development-mysql rake db:dump
```

the command fails with:

```
Don't know how to build task 'db:dump'
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930361/rake-dbmigrate-and-rake-dbcreate-both-work-on-test-database-not-development-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the `yaml_db` gem is in the `development` group of your Gemfile. This results in the fact that if you run `RAILS_ENV=development-mysql rake db:dump` Bundler loads only the general gems and not the gems from `development-mysql`.

You need to add `yaml_db` to a group named `development-mysql`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @timo-shilling. That was exactly it. I put it accidentally into the dev group

Answer (score 0):

Without using gem, you can dump your database with `(RAILS_ENV=production) rake db:dump`.
In your *lib/tasks/db.rake*

```
namespace :db do
    desc "Dumps the database to backups"
    task :dump => :environment do
        cmd = nil
        with_config do |app, host, db, user|
            cmd = "db_password pg_dump -h host -d #{db} -U db_username > /path/to/file/#{db}.psql"
        end
        puts cmd
        exec cmd
    end
    private
    def with_config
        yield Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore,
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:host],
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database],
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:username]
    end
end
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/hopsoft/56ba6f55fe48ad7f8b90) is the source.

Comment: Handy; but seems to be assuming you're using postgres ..